# Exceed rank 8, 9, and 11

Tags: no-game-no-life

No Game No Life have 16 race and ranked from 1 to 16, based on this [wiki](http://no-game-no-life.wikia.com/wiki/Exceed)

There are :

1. Old Deus
2. Phantasma
3. Elemental
4. Dragonia
5. Gigant
6. Flügel
7. Elf
8. ?
9. ?
10. Exmachina
11. ?
12. Dhampir
13. Lunamana
14. Werebeast
15. Seiren
16. Imanity

Anyone know about race ranked 8, 9 , and 11 ?

Comment: Haven't read the light novels, but all sources on the Japanese internet point to the positions of the dwarves/faeries/demons being unknown as of this time.

Comment: Does Tet belong to any of these or is he unique?

Comment: so they already mentioned but not the rank ?

Comment: @SeptianPrimadewa Yes, the "missing" races have been named (in the light novels, anyway), as you can see at the bottom of the article you linked. Just not ranked.

Comment: @user1306322 he is a god, so he is unique ;)

Comment: In light novel told that exmachina can easily killed a demonia. Maybe demonia is 11th?

Answer (score 4):

As also stated in the comment's the 3 remaining races are already known and are the

- dwarf
- fairy
- demonia

The 3 respected race's have not yet been ranked, but will most likely fill the blank spots of rank 8, 9 and 11.

[image: Source No game no life wiki]